# How do I serialize serialiable data in my class that uses IXmlSerializable?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I have a class the implements `IXmlSerializable` like below:

```
public class SomeClass : IXmlSerializable
{
    public SomeSerializableClass ClassA { get; set; }

    public SomeNonSerializableClass ClassB { get; set; }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.ReadStartElement("RootElement");

        do
        {
            if (reader.Name == "SomeNonSerializableClass")
            {
                // Perform custom serialization
            }
            else if (reader.Name == "SomeSerializableClass")
            {
                // I just want to use the SomeSerializableClass's
                // already implemented serialization process here.
            }
        }
        while (reader.Name != "RootElement");

        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }
}
```

Let's just look at the `ReadXml` implementation for this example. I have two classes, one is name `SomeNonSerializableClass`, which is why the `SomeClass` class has `IXmlSerializable` implemented. I then also have the `SomeSerializableClass`, which can be serialized natively, using `XmlSerializer` for example.

I'm serializing `SomeClass` using `XmlSerializer`, and I could manually serialize `SomeSerializableClass`, but why would I if it already can be serialized using .NETs serialization classes? So how can I just serialize it and pass it into the reader/writer?

Comment: Do I understand it right that `SomeSerializableClass` doesn't implement `IXmlSerializable`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `XmlSerializer` for that type. Something like:

```
public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
{
    reader.ReadStartElement("SomeClass");

    do
    {
        if (reader.Name == "ClassB")
        {
            reader.ReadStartElement();

            // manually deserialize SomeNonSerializableClass here

            reader.ReadEndElement();
        }
        else if (reader.Name == "ClassA")
        {
            reader.ReadStartElement();
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeSerializableClass));
            ClassA = (SomeSerializableClass)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.ReadEndElement();
        }
    }
    while (reader.Name != "SomeClass");

    reader.ReadEndElement();
}

public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("ClassB");
    // manually serialize SomeNonSerializableClass here
    writer.WriteEndElement();

    writer.WriteStartElement("ClassA");
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeSerializableClass));
    serializer.Serialize(writer, ClassA);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

Comment: I have to remove the ReadStartElement in your code above because that would take it off the start node and throw an exception for the ReadSubtree Method. After that I get the following exception from the XmlSerializer: {"<SomeSerializableClass xmlns=''> was not expected."}

Comment: Sorry, the `ReadToSubtree()` shouldn't be there. And of course your `WriteXml()` needs to follow the same structure too, so I have added the code there too. This code works for me.